# OleDbCommand is so slow

Tags: .net, vb.net, oledb

I have to get the total sum of a numeric column from a local Paradox database. I'm using the code listed below but to get the result it takes more than 6 minutes. The table has more than 340000 rows.

```
Dim sbConnection = New StringBuilder("")

sbConnection.Append("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;")
sbConnection.Append("Extended Properties=Paradox 7.x;")
sbConnection.AppendFormat("Data Source={0};", pathDB1)

Dim queryString As String = "SELECT SUM([Purchase Lines].Quantity) FROM [Purchase Lines]"
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(sbConnection.ToString())
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)

     connection.Open()

     Dim cnt = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar())
 End Using
```

Comment: Well... you can't get more simple than that. The problem might be that it's on an access database. Especially if the database is being updated at the same time.

Comment: No, the database is not updated at the same time.

Comment: How long it takes to run this query as a stored procedure in Paradox database?

Comment: It takes 2 or 3 seconds

Comment: I think it is something in the interplay between OleDB and the paradox driver or the paradox driver itself.  Having nothing better to do I created 350,000 rows in an old Access DB, then summed them: 226 milliseconds